# Polymer data-ng-change vs data-ng-blur

Tags: angularjs, polymer, textfield, angularjs-ng-change

I have a paper-input item

```
<paper-input label="Test"  data-ng-model="item" data-ng-blur="onBlur(x)" data-ng-change="onChange(y)"> </paper-input>
```

In the controller, the functions are defined as -

```
function onBlur(x)
{
...
}

function onChange(y)
{
...
}
```

On losing focus on the item, onBlur is called correctly. However, on changing data in the item, the onChange function is not called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behaviour of data-ng-change is to fire events only when you focus out of the element. To fire an event when changing data in the element, I used data-ng-keyup